# Is this radius $1.5$ or $1.414$ ... or what is the smoothest/best curve to connect a midpoint with a corner?

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

Start with a unit square and designate two points, A and B. A is the midpoint of the left side. B is the top-right corner.

I want to draw a circular arc through those two points. The arc must pass perpendicularly through A and diagonally through B. In other words the tangent of the circle at point A is perpendicular to the left side of the square, and the tangent of the circle at point B forms a 45-degree angle with the top side of the square.

This necessarily means the radius to A coincides with the left side, and the radius to B forms a 45-degree angle against the top side.

The question is, **what is the radius of the circle?** When I draw it out, it appears to be either 1.5 or $\sqrt{2}$. This is pretty weird and I can't figure out what is the truth.

**EDIT: Okay, so apparently this circle is impossible to construct** with the conditions I specified. But this is even more distressing. I need a curve that goes through both points and is tangent the way I want. What would be the smoothest curve? Would the radius of curvature just change linearly from 1.5 to 1.414...?

If you're curious, this arose from designing a train game. This particular piece of curved track has to connect a straight track coming from the left with a straight track going to the top-right. There **must** be a smooth curve to connect this and I want to know how to describe it. I will also need to know the length of the curve in order to have a track cost based on reality.

**Edit 2:** Thanks to Rahul for the solution that still uses a circle. The circle passes perpendicularly through the square's left midpoint and also lies tangent to the square's diagonal. Then just continue on in a straight line that will pass through the top-right corner at a 45-degree angle.

[image]

It took me a while to find r in terms of the square side length but I think I've got it now that I realize there is another r by symmetry on the bottom.

$a = b + c = h + \frac{1}{2}$

$b + h = \frac{1}{2}$

$r^2 = 2(h + \frac{1}{2})^2$ and $h + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$

From my knowledge of sine and cosine, I can see that $h$ is just $1 - \sin{45^o} = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \approx 0.293$, therefore:

$r = \sqrt{2}(h + \frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{2}(\frac{3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) = \frac{3\sqrt{2} - 2}{2} = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} - 1 \approx 1.121$

I wasn't convinced that $b = h$ and $c = \frac{1}{2}$ even though they look pretty close in the diagram. And after checking, I find them **different.**

$b + h = \frac{1}{2}$

$b = \frac{1}{2} - 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{2} \approx 0.207$

$z = b\sqrt{2} \approx 0.293$

So the length of the whole path is the arc + z:

$\frac{1}{8}2\pi r + \sqrt{2}\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4} (\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} - 1) + \frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{2} \approx 1.174$

...which makes sense because we're connecting a midpoint with a corner, so it should be a little longer than 1.

Comment: If one does not falsely assume that "the tangent of the circle at point B forms a 45-degree angle with the top side of the square" one can still find the circle.

Comment: A simple curve that satisfies your requirements is the parabola $y=(1+x^2)/2$. If you want a geometric construction, an alternative is to construct a circle passing through A horizontally and tangent to the /-shaped diagonal of the square. From where the circle meets the diagonal, continue along the diagonal to B.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks, I think the circle plus straight line is the simplest way to do it. I edited the OP again since you didn't post it as an answer, but if you do I will accept it as the best path from a midpoint to a corner.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because you specifically asked for the *smoothest* curve, and the arc + line segment is clearly not the smoothest because it changes curvature abruptly. Anyway, since you've put in the effort to work out all the details, you're welcome to post an answer and accept it yourself.

Comment: @Rahul Right, well unfortunately I want several conflicting things: smooth, simple, "best"... I am not even sure what "smooth" or "smoothest" means mathematically, but I **think** it would mean a radius of curvature with the least variance. So ideally it would be constant (a circle). It may look bad to have it change suddenly, but remember the point is to connect a straight track with another straight track. Consider the case of a left track connecting a vertical track. This **can** be done with one quarter circle, but we still have the abrupt change from straight to curve at 2 places...

Comment: ...Your suggestion is no different that way, so it's good. Left track (straight line) connects to a circle, circle connects to a diagonal line, line connects to another line in same direction. The only caveat is to minimize cost, you want the shortest track. This would be a straight line between 2 points, but with no curve, the train change directions instantly, and derail. So you hafta have some curve. Your parabola solution might have a shorter path, but we could also chose any circle with arbitrarily high radius of curve, to the point it is just a corner, so I am not sure how to optimize.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, your last drawing is lying to you. You have the notion that the point that's the center of your circle will be one unit directly above the top-left corner, but that's not actually the case.  (The problem, incidentally, comes where you say 'the tangent at $B$ forms a 45-degree angle with the top side of the square'; that's not correct for the unique circular arc that crosses horizontally through $A$ and passes through $B$.)

In fact, you can work the other way, and figure out exactly how far above that point your center (we'll call it $O$) *does* have to be: let that distance (from $O$ to the corner) be $x$.  Then the condition that $OA$ is a radius says that the radius is $x+\frac12$; and the condition that $OB$ is a radius says that the radius is $\sqrt{1+x^2}$.  Now, for it to actually be a circle, these two things have to be equal; in other words, $x+\frac12 = \sqrt{1+x^2}$.  Can you figure out what $x$ has to be from those two conditions?

Comment: I could do it with the quadratic formula, but the fact that my circle doesn't exist, this changes my problem. It's supposed to connect a straight train track from the left to a straight train track going diagonally top-right. I edited the OP. What I want to know now is what is the smoothest curve to connect this, and what is it's length?

Answer (score 2):

There is no circle with all the properties you ask.  As the tangent line is perpendicular to the radius at a point, having the circle meet the side at A perpendicularly requires the center of the circle to be on the extension of the left side of the square.  Having the tangent at an angle of 45 degrees at the upper right corner requires the center to be on the diagonal line you have drawn with a slope of $-1$.  Those two lines intersect in a point that is $1.5$ from A and $\sqrt 2$ from B.  You have to decide what you want to give up.  You can move A upward to $2-\sqrt 2$ and have a circle of radius $\sqrt 2$ and probably be closest to your desire.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to the updated question: the canonical way of connecting two points with specified tangencies is via *spline* curves; in particular, a cubic spline has exactly the right number of constraints involved to pass through a pair of specified points with a pair of specified velocity vectors. Interpolating splines for value and first derivative are called [Hermite splines](http://www.cubic.org/docs/hermite.htm).

In this case, you could formulate the problem in terms of a parametric plane curve $\vec{f}(t) = \langle x(t), y(t)\rangle$; your conditions would then be $\vec{f}(0) = \langle 0, 0.5\rangle$, $\vec{f}(1) = \langle 1, 1\rangle$, $\dfrac{d\vec{f}}{dt}(0) = \langle 1, 0\rangle$, and $\dfrac{d\vec{f}}{dt}(1) = \left\langle \frac{\sqrt{2}}2, \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\right\rangle$.  It might be even easier to cast it as a 'one-dimensional' curve $y=y(x)$, though; in that case the conditions become $y(0) = 0.5$, $y(1) = 1$, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}(0) = 0$, and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}(1)=1$.

This latter is easily solved with Wolfram Alpha (the magic phrase in this case is `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{0},0.5,0},{{1},1, 1}},x]`) and in fact reveals a *quadratic* solution: $y=\frac12(x^2+1)$

It's easy to see that this shape has all the right properties.  It's relatively straightforward to calculate the length of the curve, as well; plugging in `length of y=1/2(x^2+1) from x=0 to x=1` to Alpha yields a value of $\approx 1.15$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised at your puzzle. What you have discovered is that the circle you want does not exist. Once you specify that it go through both $A$ and $B$ and have a horizontal tangent at $A$ (in your picture) you have enough information to draw the circle. The radius will be determined, as will the angle at $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you cannot draw such a circle that satisfies all you requirements.

So if you want the circle to pass point A, and have the 45 degree angle, plus the left side of the square being aligned with one of its diameter - then the circle is fixed, I.e. you could only draw one circle like that, and that circle you have does not pass through point B.